# Артефакты при рендере виджета

Tags: python, pyqt5, pdf

В QTDesigner создана форма. На форме есть graphicsView. При помощи pyqtgraph рисуем графики.
Необходимо график вывести в pdf.
делаю следующим образом

```
pixmap = QPixmap(self.graphicsViewControlValve.size())
self.graphicsViewControlValve.render(QPainter(pixmap))
```

Все преобразуется как надо, но есть одна проблема. При рендере на изображении появляются артефакты, когда больше, когда меньше. Поиск нашел похожую проблему https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73461816/qgraphicsscene-artifacts-when-rendering-and-saving-the-scene-to-a-file , но у меня не получилось использовать данный метод. Толи я не разобрался, то ли у меня немного другая задача. Что нужно добавить в код, что бы избавиться от артефактов? Если можно по подробнее, пока не очень силен в терминах.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Варианты проявления могут отличаться, но в основном в верхней части картинки. Как назло сегодня не хочет жесткие варианты предоставлять. Первая можно сказать отличная, немного вверху. На второй немного смазалось изображение. Третья это вчерашний вариант сохранился. Были случаи наложения картинки друг на друга
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Последний вариант "удачный" получился

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
QPainter painter(pixmap);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
```

Для графиков в Qt, можно также **antialiasing** юзать от `QPainter`, но он снизит точность рисования.

Comment: Да, я читал про это, но что-то у меня не получилось его применить, какие-то ошибки были. Где-то что-то не верно записывал. У Вас судя по синтаксису не Python?

Comment: @ИгорьФедоров, у меня плюсы, но мне в графиках нужна точность и сглаживание не использовал. Попробуйте с масштабом поля поиграться либо с радиусом точек, чтобы визуально сделать его ровным, но я мало с графиками работал в Qt.

Comment: что-то у меня после antialiasing в pdf перестает выводить. Причем что за ошибка, определить не получается, так как ромбиками пишет. Буду еще документацию читать.

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу немного другим методом. graphicsView преобразовываю в картинку при помощи pyqtgraph.exporters, а затем картинку вставляю в pdf документ

```
exporter = pyqtgraph.exporters.ImageExporter(self.graphicsViewControlValve.plotItem)
exporter.params.param('width').setValue(400, blockSignal=exporter.widthChanged)
exporter.params.param('height').setValue(390, blockSignal=exporter.heightChanged)
exporter.export('fileName.png')
```

Качество картинки получается достойное.